# How to make a sprite button in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

My project needs so many buttons. But for each button I make, it has to load every images even though I make same buttons like this :

```
auto btn = cocos2d::ui::Button::create("images/bone01.png","images/bone02.png","");
```

I think it's very wasteful in respect of system cost. I want to make only 1 texture2d* and use it when making buttons. I searched many times with keyword, 'cocos2d-x button texture...' but there is no answer I could find. Is there any method to use texture in creating Button, or should I make a class inherited by Sprite class which contains touchEventListner and function parameters? if so, how can I start to create function to use method like this :

```
btn->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_0(HelloWorld::touchBoard, this));
```

just a little example would be okay to me.

=============================================

I made a singleton Class and put all Buttons, and tried to use it when it's needed. But failed because Button is autoreleased when it is created, so if I use it another cpp, like :

```
auto appleBtn = DataClass::getInstance()->_appleBtn;
```

an error occurs like this :

```
 Expression : child->_parent == nullptr
```

I may succeed in this way by using retain() & release(), but I would rather to use safer way.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not have any experience with cocos2d, I assume it will load this texture in memory only once, and use this information for all buttons. Isn't it possible to make a button class and inherited all the same buttons from this class? Again I have no clue how cocos2d works but any other game engine this should be possible :)

Comment: I'm not sure it'll work since i'm very new in cocos2d-x. I'll try it soon.

Comment: I tried it and failed ;-( but thanks for advise anyways